# Populate hiddenfield after autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to populate the value of a hiddenfield after the user clicked on an autocomplete-entry.
The code I tried looks like this:

```
<input type=hidden id="myHiddenField" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectItem(li) {
        return false;
    }
    function formatItem(row) {
        return row[0] + "<br><i>" + row[1] + "</i>";
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myInputField").autocomplete("../test.asp", {
            minChars: 3,
            matchSubset: 10,
            matchContains: 1,
            cacheLength: 10,
            onItemSelect: selectItem,
            formatItem: formatItem,
            selectOnly: 1,

            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#myHiddenField").val(ui.item.value)
            }


        });
    });
</script>
```

The autocomplete is working fine, but I am not able to set the value of my hidden-field. I also tried to set it to a normal string like this `$("#myHiddenField").val("test")`, but that didn't work either.
Any idea how to populate it?

This is the autocomplete I am using: [pastebin-link](http://pastebin.com/PZqtRSPQ)
And here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CaC4/1/), which is not working properly although.
Autocomplete source: [Github-link](https://github.com/johnantoni/jquery.autocomplete). (Note: In this case, I have to use this autocomplete-script, I am not able to use the newer ones.)

Comment: <input type=hidden id="myHiddenField" value=""> There might be error here. Change it to <input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" value="">

Comment: By the way, could you please provide fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @cubuzoa thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately that was not the cause of the error. I tried to create a jsfiddle, but it's not working as intended. Here it is for reference: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CaC4/1/)

Comment: Having the link to the doc of the autocomplete plugin would probably help.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine YOu are right. I added it to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution like this;

```
function selectItem(li) {
    return false;
}

function formatItem(row) {
    return row[0] + "<br><i>" + row[1] + "</i>";
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var programmingLanguages = [
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"

    ];
    $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: programmingLanguages ,
        minChars: 3,
        matchSubset: 10,
        matchContains: 1,
        cacheLength: 10,
        onItemSelect: selectItem,
        formatItem: formatItem,
        selectOnly: 1,

        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#hfieldvisible").val(ui.item.value)
        }


    });
});
```

I have added `source` param to autocomplete. And I have also added one item to HTML

```
<input type="text" id="hfieldvisible" value="">
```

in order to show you that it is adding selected item to that input.

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6S46E/

**Updated (JSON remote)**: You can json remote version here http://jsfiddle.net/u5beu/1/

Comment: Thanks! Now as you may see in the OP, I have a classic asp-file which returns a JSON. I simplified it to this: `<%    
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"    
Response.Write("[{ ""value"": ""ActionScript"", ""id"": 31 }, { ""value"": ""AppleScript"", ""id"": 2 }, { ""value"": ""JavaScript"", ""id"": 3 }, { ""value"": ""Haskell"", ""id"": 33 },  { ""value"": ""Training"", ""id"": 32}]")
%>`. I also replaced `programmingLanguages` with `mysite.asp`, but now the autocomplete doesn't work anymore. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Am i right that in your case I just need the jQuery 2.0.2 source in my file?

Comment: Thanks. I can remove my autocomplete script (see Github) and use 2.0.2 instead?

Comment: Yes you can. Find minified version of autocomplete. 2.0.2. And test on jsfiddle